# What did I do to remove the Terminal Window But Preserve Running Processes?

Tags: terminal

I was using Terminal and accidentally fat-fingered some shortcut. The *apparent* result was the window was destroyed and all of the running processes (some local dev server processes running in the foreground) were put into the background. I tried everything I could think of to find the window (e.g. mission control), but even after quitting Terminal completely the local server processes are still happily running. What did I do, and is it reversible (barring reboot)? The processes were ruby and node processes if that's somehow relevant.

Edit: I forgot to mention these processes were running from inside tmux.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the thing I forgot to mention turned out to be the most critical. Opening a new window and running `tmux attach -t 0` fixed it.

Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22781/how-to-recover-a-shell-after-a-disconnection.

Must have closed the window with command-w.